# Kendo UI grid custom datasource URL

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, kendo-ui

I have a comboBox called clientCCBox, I need a javascript that retrieves the selected option value, wich will be the client id, and then passes it on the kendo grid datasource read property as follow:

```
<kendo:dataSource-transport-read url="/read.html?*clientID*"/>
```

I've been trying to use this js snippet to recover the selected value; the document write is there to visually see if it actually retrieved the value, but it displays nothing. How would I once I get the clientID use it in HTML?

```
<script> 
    function onSelect(e){
        var clientId = clientCCBox.value();   
        document.write(clienteId);
    }
</script>
```

If I do manage to pass clientID on the querystring, the following code on the controller would return a list and populate the grid right?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/read.html*")
public @ResponseBody List<Workers> read(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return workerDAO.listWorker(Integer.parseInt(request.getQueryString()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your additional parameters using `parameterMap` attribute in `kendo:dataSource-transport` tag.

Example:

```
<kendo:dataSource-transport parameterMap="additionalParameters">
    <kendo:dataSource-transport-read url="/ListBeer" type="GET" contentType="application/json"/>
</kendo:dataSource-transport>
```

Where `additionalParameters` is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var theId = "xyz";

    function additionalParameters(data, type) {
        if (type === "read") {
            return "id=" + theId;
        }
        return data;
    }
</script>
```

Here, I would be loading data from the following url `/ListBeer?id=xyz` where `xyz` is the value of `theId`.

You can also send more than one parameter:

```
function additionalParameters(data, type) {
    if (type === "read") {
        return "id=" + data + "&param=" + JSON.stringify(data);
    }
    return "param= "+ JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Data" event on the read action parameter for the drop down to specify dynamic javascript parameters to the drop down. Note the exact syntax for the .Read method. Often you see the syntax .Read("ActionName", "ControllerName") but we want the other overloaded version of .Read:

```
.DataSource(data => data.Read(read => read.Action("GetDropDownValues", "Quote").Data("getCriteria")))

function getCriteria() {
    return {
        id: "put value here",
        anotherParameter: 55
    };
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have answered assuming MVC.Net while the question is tagged java / jsp.

Comment: You are right. Sorry about that. I'll let the information stand in case it's useful for MVC.Net people using Kendo.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the client id in the data field of the transport.

Look at the following link.

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportcreatedata-objectstringfunction

this is part of jquery not kendo ui

Comment: should I just leave the data field as data = clientId ? Isn't there a specific markup to retrieve a JS var?